# Consistent colour across Matplotlib Groupby Graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I am attempting to create a **scatter pie plot** that groups by 2 columns, Column1 & Column 2 where the colour in the pie (if numbers are the same) is decided by Column 3.

See my example below of where I am:

[image]

This graph shows Column 1 (y-axis) and Column 2 (x-axis). The colour is dictated by Column 3.

But with the code I use the colours do not stay consistent across graphs and if the same Column 3 appears with a different Column 2 or Column 3 value it assigns it a different colour.

I have attempted using cmaps and manually assigning colours but I cannot keep it consistent across each column 2.

See my current code below:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticks
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import numpy as np

def draw_pie(dist, 
             xpos, 
             ypos, 
             size, 
             color,
             ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(70,60))

    # for incremental pie slices
    cumsum = np.cumsum(dist)
    cumsum = cumsum/ cumsum[-1]
    pie = [0] + cumsum.tolist()

    for r1, r2 in zip(pie[:-1], pie[1:]):
        angles = np.linspace(2 * np.pi * r1, 2 * np.pi * r2)
        x = [0] + np.cos(angles).tolist()
        y = [0] + np.sin(angles).tolist()

        xy = np.column_stack([x, y])

        ax.scatter([xpos], [ypos], marker=xy, s=size,c=color)

    return ax


colors = {'Group A':'red', 'Group B':'green', 'Group C':'blue', 'Group D':'yellow', 'Group E':'yellow', 'Group F':'yellow', 'Group G':'yellow', 'Group H':'yellow'}


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(94,70))
for (x,y), d in dataset.groupby(['Column 1','Column 2']):
    dist = d['Column 3'].value_counts()
    draw_pie(dist, x, y, 50000, ax=ax,color=dataset['Column 3'].map(colors))


params = {'legend.fontsize': 100}
plt.rcParams.update(params)
#plt.legend(dataset["Column 3"],markerscale=.4,frameon=True,framealpha=1,ncol=3,loc=(0.00, -0.3), bbox_to_anchor=(0.0, 0., 0.5, 1.25),handletextpad=1,markerfirst=True,facecolor='lightgrey',mode='expand',borderaxespad=-16)


ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticks.MultipleLocator(1))
full = plt.Rectangle((-0.05, 4.25), 2.10, 2, color='g', alpha=0.15)
partial = plt.Rectangle((-0.05, 2.25), 2.10, 2, color='orange', alpha=0.15)
low = plt.Rectangle((-0.05, 0.25), 2.10, 2, color='r', alpha=0.15)
ax.add_patch(full)
ax.add_patch(partial)
ax.add_patch(low)
plt.xticks(fontsize=120)
plt.yticks(fontsize=100)
plt.ylim([0, 6.75]) 
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Ideally the output graph based on the data (I will copy in below) should be like the below graph (I have placed a number in each pie to define what colour should be there)

[image]

Here is the full data used for the graph:

```
Column 1    3       2   Colour Group Desired
First Line  Group A 6   1
First Line  Group A 6   1
First Line  Group A 6   1
First Line  Group C 6   3
First Line  Group B 6   2
First Line  Group B 6   2
First Line  Group B 6   2
First Line  Group A 6   1
First Line  Group A 6   1
First Line  Group C 6   3
First Line  Group A 6   1
Second Line Group A 6   1
Second Line Group A 6   1
Second Line Group A 6   1
Second Line Group C 6   3
Second Line Group B 6   2
Second Line Group B 6   2
Second Line Group B 6   2
Second Line Group A 4.5 1
Second Line Group A 6   1
Second Line Group C 6   3
Second Line Group A 6   1
Third Line  Group A 1   1
Third Line  Group A 6   1
Third Line  Group A 1   1
Third Line  Group C 6   3
Third Line  Group B 3.5 2
Third Line  Group B 3.5 2
Third Line  Group B 3.5 2
Third Line  Group A 1   1
Third Line  Group A 1   1
Third Line  Group C 4   3
Third Line  Group A 1   1
```

Additionally I would like to add a label in each section of the pie with the count of distinct(Column 3).

Comment: I added a small piece of text to the Edit in my comment in which I explain how the pie charts can be made smaller, such that it looks more like your original plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently I came up with the following solution to fix the issue with the colours:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticks
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import numpy as np

def draw_pie(dist, 
             xpos, 
             ypos, 
             size, 
             ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,6))
    
    # The colors, corresponding to the values 1, 2 and 3:
    # 1 is tab:blue
    # 2 is tab:orange
    # 3 is tab:green
    # Of course, you can change this
    colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green']
    
    # for incremental pie slices
    cumsum = np.cumsum(dist)
    cumsum = cumsum/ cumsum[-1]
    pie = [0] + cumsum.tolist()

    for r1, r2, i in zip(pie[:-1], pie[1:], range(0, len(dist))):
    
        # If no counts present, skip this one
        if dist[i] == 0:
            continue
    
        angles = np.linspace(2 * np.pi * r1, 2 * np.pi * r2)
        x = [0] + np.cos(angles).tolist()
        y = [0] + np.sin(angles).tolist()

        xy = np.column_stack([x, y])
        ax.scatter([xpos], [ypos], marker=xy, s=size, color=colors[i])

    return ax
    
#colors = {'Group A':'red', 'Group B':'green', 'Group C':'blue', 'Group D':'yellow', 'Group E':'yellow', 'Group F':'yellow', 'Group G':'yellow', 'Group H':'yellow'}

# Read dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,5))

for (x,y), d in dataset.groupby(['Column 1','Column 2']):

    # Only interested in the 'Column 3' column, as this one
    # contains the values 1-2-3
    d = d['Colour Group Desired']
    
    # Count how often each value (1-2-3) occurs and store
    # this in a list (count for value i located at list index 
    # i-1)   
    dist = list()
    for i in [1,2,3]:
        dist.append(d[d==i].count())
        
        
    # Call your draw_pie function
    draw_pie(dist, x, y, 500, ax=ax)
   
    
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticks.MultipleLocator(1))
full = plt.Rectangle((-0.05, 4.25), 2.10, 2, color='g', alpha=0.15)
partial = plt.Rectangle((-0.05, 2.25), 2.10, 2, color='orange', alpha=0.15)
low = plt.Rectangle((-0.05, 0), 2.10, 2.25, color='r', alpha=0.15)
ax.add_patch(full)
ax.add_patch(partial)
ax.add_patch(low)
plt.xticks(fontsize=10)
plt.yticks(fontsize=8)
plt.ylim([0, 6.75]) 
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Small note to start with, I changed all sizes by a factor of 10 such that the plot fits on my screen (*e.g.* the figsize). You probably want to use your original values again, but this doesn't matter for the question anyway.

The first change I made was to the loop body of the `for (x,y), d in dataset.groupby(['Column 1','Column 2'])` loop. Instead of using `dist = d['Column 3'].value_counts()`, I create an empty array. Subsequently, I loop over the values `1`, `2` and `3`. In each iteration, I check how many rows match the specific value and append the outcome to the list. In this way, I end up with a list of size 3, in which the first element corresponds to the amount of rows that equal `1`, the second element corresponds to the amount of rows that equal `2` and the third element corresponds to the amount of rows that equal `3`. The advantage is that I can also keep track of values that occur 0 times.

Secondly, I changed the `draw_pie` function a bit. However, since I do not fully understand the meaning of a group in terms of the colour, I commented out the `colors` dictionary. It looks as if `1` always corresponds to `Group A`, `2` always corresponds to `Group B` and `3` always corresponds to `Group C`. I made use of this observation and defined another `colors` variable (in the `draw_pie` function). Instead of a dictionary, `colors` is now a list (where the first element corresponds to the value `1`, the second element corresponds to the value `2` and the third element corresponds to the value `3`). I changed your `for` loop from `for r1, r2 in zip(pie[:-1], pie[1:])` to `for r1, r2, i in zip(pie[:-1], pie[1:], range(0, len(dist)))`. The advantage is that I can now use the iteration variable `i` to get the proper color from the `colors` list. In addition, I added a small `if` statement which checks if there are exactly 0 occurences. If that is the case, I just skip the remainder of the loop and draw nothing (if you don't skip these cases, it will draw a very thin line instead. Try this for yourself by removing it).

If I run the code, I get the following result:
[image: Result from the code]

Unfortunately, I was not successful in adding the labels. I tried using the [`Axes.text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html?highlight=axes%20text#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text) method, but I couldn't get the labels to be placed at the proper locations.

---

## Edit

I decided to change the body of the `draw_pie` function. In this new version, we draw an `Axes` instance at the desired `(xpos, ypos)` location. This involves some transformations: first a transformation from data coordinates to display coordinates and subsequently a transformation from display coordinates to figure coordinates. See [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) for an explanation. The advantage is that we can now plot a pie chart inside the created axes using the [`Axes.pie`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie.html?highlight=axes%20pie#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie) method. This method has some nice options, such as adding labels!

However, there is a catch. Before we start drawing the pie charts, we need to already fix the `xlim` and the `ylim` values of the main `Axes`. If we don't do this (and do it *after* plotting the pie charts), the pie charts will *no longer be located at the proper positions*. Therefore, I have moved the code which sets the `xlim` and `ylim` values before the first time we call the `draw_pie` function. I also removed to call to `plt.tight_layout()`, as this will (unfortunately) also cause the pie charts to no longer be located at the proper locations.

As a small side note, I changed the manner in which the background colors are drawn. Instead of using `patches`, I now use the [`Axes.axhspan`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhspan.html) method. With this method, you can still control the y-locations, but the width will extend infinitely (meaning that the colors remain if you scroll left/right). If you don't want this, you can remove it again :).

See the new version of the code below (I note once more, I changed all sizes such that it fits on my computer screen. You probably want to substitute your original sizes again):

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticks
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import numpy as np

def draw_pie(dist, 
             xpos, 
             ypos, 
             size, 
             ax=None,
             fig=None):
    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,6))
    
    # Transform xpos and ypos to figure coordinates by the
    # following steps:
    # 1. First transform xpos and ypos to data coordinates
    # 2. Transform the data coordinates back to figure coordinates
    xfig, yfig   = ax.transData.transform((xpos, ypos))
    trans_to_fig = fig.transFigure.inverted()
    xfig, yfig   = trans_to_fig.transform((xfig, yfig))
    
    # Calculate figure coordinates from the desired pie chart size
    # given in pixels
    size = trans_to_fig.transform((size, 0))[0]
    
    # Add axes at data coordinates xpos and ypos. On these axes,
    # the pie chart will be plotted
    ax_pie = fig.add_axes([xfig-0.5*size, yfig-0.5*size, size, size])
    
    # Plot the pie chart (with some special options)
    textprops = {'color'      : 'w',
                 'fontweight' : 'bold', 
                 'fontsize'   :  10,
                 'va'         : 'center',
                 'ha'         : 'center'
                }            
    labels = [str(i) if not i == 0 else "" for i in dist]
    labeldistance = 0.5
    
    if sum(not x==0 for x in dist) == 1: # Ensures we plot the label in the center
        labeldistance = 0.0              # if we have only one entry
    
    ax_pie.pie(dist, labels=labels, labeldistance=labeldistance, textprops=textprops)

    return ax_pie
    

# Read dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.txt')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,5))

# Important, limits must be set before calling draw_pie function!
# (Otherwise, the data coordinates will change, which will break
# the transform sequence inside the draw_pie function!)
ax.set_xlim([-0.2, 2.2]) # Tweak these values for the desired output
ax.set_ylim([0, 6.75])

# Make sure the string from 'Column 1' is displayed again
ax.set_xticks([0, 1, 2])
ax.set_xticklabels(['First Line', 'Second Line', 'Third Line'])

# Remainder of formatting
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticks.MultipleLocator(1))  
plt.xticks(fontsize=10)
plt.yticks(fontsize=8)

# Define float values for 'Column 1' (easier for transformation,
# we have already put the text back there using ax.set_xticklabels)
column1_to_float = {'First Line':0, 'Second Line':1, 'Third Line':2}

for (x,y), d in dataset.groupby(['Column 1','Column 2']):

    # Only interested in the 'Column 3' column, as this one
    # contains the values 1-2-3
    d = d['Colour Group Desired']
    
    # Count how often each value (1-2-3) occurs and store
    # this in a list (count for value i located at list index 
    # i-1)   
    dist = list()
    for i in [1,2,3]:
        dist.append(d[d==i].count())
        
    # Call your draw_pie function
    draw_pie(dist, column1_to_float[x], y, 100, ax=ax, fig=fig)

# Plot the colours (note: using axhspan, they extend the full 
# horizontal direction, even while scrolling)
ax.axhspan(0   , 2.25, fc='r'     , ec=None, alpha=0.15)
ax.axhspan(2.25, 4.25, fc='orange', ec=None, alpha=0.15)
ax.axhspan(4.25, 6.75, fc='g'     , ec=None, alpha=0.15)

# Unfortunately, tight_layout can no longer be used. If we do use this,
# the pie charts will no longer be at the proper positions...
# plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

If I run this code, I get the following output:
[image: Edit results]

Just to mention it, you can decrease the size of the pie charts by adjusting the `size` argument to the `draw_pie` function (I just liked the output above :) ). But keep in mind that in this case, you also want to decrease the `fontsize` specified in the `textprops` dictionary in the body of the `draw_pie` function. As an example (`size = 63`, `fontsize=7`):

[image: Edit results, smaller pie charts]